# How can i find the similarity in 2 arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, compare

I have 2 arrays:

```
var arr1 = ['2','3','4'];
var arr2 = ['2'] or ['2', '3'] or ['2','3','4'] or ['3', '4', '5'] or ['5','6'];
```

If arr2 has similarity to arr1 return true, and if not similar like ['5','6'] then return false even return false when arr2 is ['3', '4', '5'].

Comment: Do you mean that if the same values are in both arrays it should return true?

Comment: its not clear what exactly you want to test?

Comment: so you want to check if arr2 is subset of arr1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var arr1 = ['2', '3', '5', '7'];
var arr2 = ['3', '4', '8'];

for(i=0; i<arr2.length; i++){

    if(jQuery.inArray(arr2[i], arr1)== -1){
        console.log(arr2[i] + ' Is not in Arr1');
    }

}
```

4 Is not in Arr1
8 Is not in Arr1

Answer (score 0):

just use `JSON.stringify(arr)`

```
var arr1 = ['2','3','4'];
var arr2 = ['2','3','4'] ;
var i= JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2);
alert(i);
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also

```
var array1 = ['2', '3', '5', '7'];
var array2 = ['3','9', '8'];
var diff = []; 
$.grep(array2, function( value, key ) {
   if($.inArray(value, array1) === -1){
    diff.push(value);
  }
});
if(diff.length > 0){
   console.log('diff Array is');
   console.log(diff); 
   console.log('Array2 is not a subset of Array1');
}else{
   console.log('Array2 is a subset of Array1'); 
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/5wxvagun/)